# Inserting a file in microsoft word 2011

Tags: macos, ms-office

I want to insert/embed a file in the Word Document. If i go to, Insert -> File and then select the file, it inserts the text present in that file. But i want to display it as only an icon.

If i got to Insert -> Object -> From File -> Check the Display as Icon -> Select the file, it displays an error, "The sever application, source file or item cannot be found. Make sure that application is properly installed, and that it has not been deleted, moved or renamed".

How do I make it work? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Insert->Object, Word tries to insert the file as an OLE object. This only works if Word knows how to handle the type of file you are inserting. The error message seems to indicate that Word doesn't know this.
What kind of file is it? Do you have an application on your system that can open this file?
Also note that this link will only work on the computer you're working on now. When you transfer the Word document to another computer, the link will break.

Comment: The file i'm trying to insert is an html file. I also tried inserting .zip, .txt files also. Same error. I have done this before on Windows platform without any problem.

Comment: What happens when you open the html file from the Finder?

Comment: It opens in Firefox.

Comment: Firefox has to be OLE-aware for this to work. I haven't found a definitive answer to whether it is, though.